CS50 Substitution tolower is capitalizing my A characters
Doing week 2 of CS50.Its supposed to be a ciphering algorithm. Ive gotten to the point where it ciphers my code BUT for some reason when I try testing my code and using my name, it doesnt make my second A char a lower cased a.
Key: NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB
Typing in: Armando
What I get--> ciphertext: NjzNgpe
What I want--> ciphertext: Njzngpe
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char alpha[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
                'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
int cypher[] = {};
char new[] = {};

void cypher_s(string k);
void scramble(string s, int l);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string key = argv[1];
        cypher_s(key);
        string text = get_string("plaintext: ");
        scramble(text, strlen(key));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You suck, you need a command line argument or typed too many\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

void cypher_s(string k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++)
    {
        cypher[i] = k[i];
    }
}

void scramble(string s, int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        int position = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
        {
            if (s[i] == alpha[position])
            {
                printf("Capital %c\n", s[i]);
                new[i] = cypher[position];
                position++;
            }
            else if (s[i] == tolower(alpha[position]))
            {
                printf("Lower %c\n", s[i]);
                new[i] = tolower(cypher[position]);
                position++;
            }
            else
            {
                position++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(new); j++)
    {
        printf("%c", new[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


Aside:  Don't do for (int i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++)  Why do you think you need to recompute the string length every times the loop iterates?  You don't.  Hint:  Compute the length once, before entering the loop, just as you'd do if you were doing it by hand.

Bugs:  Your global cypher and new arrays are declared with empty initializers and no explicit size, so they're effectively declared as zero-length arrays.  You can't use them at all without writing beyond them.  Increase your warning level so that your compiler will complain about those bad declarations.  Also, why are they globals?

@TomKarzes, thanks for the heads up. Ill fix these issues. As far as the global I was thinking this way when I write a function everything can access that array for example. Is it better to keep everything in a blocked scope?

It's generally better to make them either function parameters, or else local to the function.

Another approach is to keep all of the state in a struct, then pass the address of the struct.  That's generally cleaner if you have multiple state variables.

@TomKarzes I see, I haven't gotten to that point of C but good to know. Much appreciated

Trying out your code, the first thing noted was the compiler warnings returned when trying to compile your code denoting the potential for exceeding the bounds of your character arrays.
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c||In function ‘cypher_s’:|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|36|warning: array subscript i is outside array bounds of ‘int[0]’ [-Warray-bounds]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|7|note: while referencing ‘cypher’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c||In function ‘scramble’:|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|68|warning: array subscript j is outside array bounds of ‘char[0]’ [-Warray-bounds]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|8|note: while referencing ‘new’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|56|warning: array subscript i is outside array bounds of ‘char[0]’ [-Warray-bounds]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|8|note: while referencing ‘new’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|50|warning: array subscript position is outside array bounds of ‘int[0]’ [-Warray-bounds]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|7|note: while referencing ‘cypher’|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|50|warning: array subscript i is outside array bounds of ‘char[0]’ [-Warray-bounds]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/main.c|8|note: while referencing ‘new’|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Also, even though global variables are absolutely allowed, it is usual and customary to utilize variables local to each function to possibly avoid scope issues with variable references.
With that in mind and looking at suggestions to simplify your code, following is a refactored version of your code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 100

void scramble(char * s, char * x, char * c);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char * key = argv[1];
        char text[SIZE], cypher[SIZE];  /* Define strings with a specific size in lieu of a zero length */
        //cypher_s(key);
        printf("plaintext: ");  /* Do not have CS50 - using usual and customary printf/prompt method    */
        scanf("%s", text);
        //string text = get_string("plaintext: ");
        scramble(text, key, cypher);
        printf("The scrambled text is: %s\n", cypher);  /* Placed the output of the encrypted text in the main function */
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter the encryption key as a parameter\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

void scramble(char * s, char * x, char * c)
{
    char alpha[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    int l = strlen(s);  /* Length of the text to be encrypted   */
    int m = strlen(x);  /* Length of the key                    */

    strcpy(c, s);       /* Set the target string to the text    */

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)     /* Scan through the encryption key for match    */
        {
            if (s[i] == alpha[k])       /* No need for a separate index counter         */
            {
                //printf("Capital %c\n", s[i]);
                c[i] = x[k];
                break;
            }
            else if (s[i] == tolower(alpha[k]))
            {
                //printf("Lower %c\n", s[i]);
                c[i] = tolower(x[k]);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Not a character that needs to be encrypted   */
            }
        }
    }
}

Following are some key points.

Since I do not have the CS50 package installed, I opted to revert to equivalent definitions for strings and string prompting; however, feel free to utilize those functions if you wish.
The global variables were relocated to match up their scope and usage, thus removing the need for global variables.
In evaluating the "cypher" function, its only purpose was to store a character array into an integer array, so it was eliminated for simplification.
String lengths were determined in the scramble/encryption function and stored in work variables which again simplified utilization of matching and text encryption.

Following are some tests at the terminal with this refactored code.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/bin/Release$ ./Crypto NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB
plaintext: Armando
The scrambled text is: Njzngpe
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/bin/Release$ ./Crypto NQXPOMAFTRHLZGECYJIUWSKDVB
plaintext: Armando$%6__x
The scrambled text is: Njzngpe$%6__d
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Crypto/bin/Release$ 

These bits of refactoring are just one of many possible solutions to the issues you encountered, but the key takeaways from this code refactoring are:

Pay attention to all compiler warnings as they can point to possible undefined behavior such as the zero length character arrays.
When possible opt for local variables over global variables.

